# Is there a barebones application for posting to Twitter and Facebook without seeing your update stream?

Tags: facebook, twitter

I am looking for a Web Application where I can post to Twitter and Facebook, but not see the updates from the people I follow.

The stream is very distracting, sometimes I need to go make some updates but I want to save my reading for later. Is there any tool that allows this type of minimalism?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a browser add-on like [Shareaholic](http://www.shareaholic.com/). It's lightweight, fast and doesn't need you to sign up to another service.

Answer (score 1):

http://nutshellmail.com/ seems to be what you are looking for, although I haven't personally used it. You can also email/text updates to both Facebook and Twitter using their mobile services. This is how I generally update, and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Simply open this link:

http://twitter.com/intent/tweet

[image]